# PostgreSQL SELECT too slow

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

I am looking for an idea to optimize my query.

Currently, I have a table of 4M lines, I only want to retrieve the last 1000 lines of a reference:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers_material_events 
WHERE reference = 'XXXXXX' 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 1000;
```

This is the execution plan:

```
Limit  (cost=12512155.48..12512272.15 rows=1000 width=6807) (actual time=8953.545..9013.658 rows=1000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=16153 read=30342
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=12512155.48..12840015.90 rows=2810036 width=6807) (actual time=8953.543..9013.613 rows=1000 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=16153 read=30342
         ->  Sort  (cost=12511155.46..12514668.00 rows=1405018 width=6807) (actual time=8865.186..8865.208 rows=632 loops=3)
               Sort Key: date DESC
               Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 330kB
               Worker 0:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 328kB
               Worker 1:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 330kB
               Buffers: shared hit=16153 read=30342
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on customers_material_events  (cost=0.00..64165.96 rows=1405018 width=6807) (actual time=0.064..944.029 rows=1117807 loops=3)
                     Filter: ((reference)::text = 'FFFEEE'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 17188
                     Buffers: shared hit=16091 read=30342
 Planning Time: 0.189 ms
 Execution Time: 9013.834 ms
(18 rows)
```

I see the execution time is very very slow...

Comment: Does the table have indexes?

Comment: Only 'id' is primary key

Comment: Then you’ll probably benefit from adding an index on `reference` if the data is suitable, which it seems to be

Comment: Ideally the index should be a multicolumn   (reference, date) one to search and sort on. PostgreSQL would still need to access the table data for the other column data

Comment: `ORDER BY a_column DESC LIMIT N` quite often benefits from an index on `a_column`. As mentioned above, you can also add an index `reference` and `(reference, date)` or `(date, reference)`. Just experiment with adding an index, doing `ANALYZE customers_material_events ` and measure the speed -- one of these indexes can also speed up the query, but if and how much really depends on the selectivity of both columns.

Comment: Thank you for your answers
These are my first steps with postgresql
And I do not understand everything ...

Comment: For all the table : (without order/limit)...
 Planning Time: 0.084 ms
 Execution Time: 714.849 ms
(4 rows)

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal index for this query would be:

```
CREATE INDEX ON customers_material_events (reference, date);
```

That would allow you to quickly find the values for a certain `reference`, automatically ordered by `date`, so no extra sort step is necessary.